# Uploading a folder of approximately 300GB of files to Amazon Glacier

Tags: amazon-web-services, zip, 7zip, amazon-glacier

Trying to backup data from my drive which has 85Tb of data generated over time. Its a  grouping of data of about 300GB. To store it into Glacier I need to make it a single archive of 300GB and upload the file. Anybody have suggestions on how to archive and upload into Glacier. I am not looking for a better compression algorithm. Even if it makes a archive of 300GB I am good.

Comment: Where is the data stored currently?

Comment: It's in a linux mc with 100TB disk attached. I am now building a tar with the folder. Will figure need to figure out how to upload to Glacier.

Comment: Is that Linux machine EC2 instance or a physical machine

Comment: It's a physical machine

Answer (score 0):

Well looking at the size of the data it will take a long time to transfer all that data to AWS Glacier.

I will suggest use AWS Import Export service where they send a actual physical device to you, you can upload the data to that device and send it back to AWS. That will be more fast instead of uploading that size of data your self.

https://aws.amazon.com/importexport/

Comment: I have tried import/export. The solution planned is for Disaster Recovery. So it is required to back up the data whenever available and import/export is hard in that scenario.